# TYPO3 extbase ObjectManager fatal error

Tags: typo3, extbase

TYPO3 Version 7.6.19

I have created an extension to create Objects via an URL call. 
On the first call of the URL the Object is created without problems. 
When I call the action a second time the following error occurs:

> Fatal error: Class 'DN\ShoppingList\Domain\Model\ShoppingList' not found in /.../typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 4538

After clearing the System Caches in Backend the action can again be called one time. Then the error again occurs. 
Here is my code snip from the called action:

```
    case 'createShoppingList':

$shoppingList= $this->objectManager->get('DN\\ShoppingList\\Domain\\Model\\ShoppingList');

$shoppingList->setName($args['listName']);
$this->shoppingListRepository->add($shoppingList);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
$this->view->assign('value', 'true' );
break;
```

I tried injecting the ObjectManager and even instantiated it localy.

I removed the typo3temp folder and recreated it and even truncated the extbase tables cleared the caches etc.

Anybody an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Is there a reason why your using the object manager can't you just use the dependency injection via GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ShoppingList::class) ?

Comment: Do use composer ? Is the vendor and extension name correct ? Check autoload files to see if the classes are loaded.